# Disable Jest setTimeout mock

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

I'm writing a Jest test for code that depends on a websocket library.

The websocket library is mocked.  I want to send a message, wait for async actions to complete, and check the response.

```
it('sends a message and gets a response', () => {
  processor(ws).sendMessage()  // do a bunch of async stuff, call websocket.sendMessage()
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(ws.getResponse()).toEqual('all done')
  }, 100)
})
```

Unfortunately because Jest mocks setTimeout, setTimeout fails.  If I run `jest.runAllTimers()`, the timeout happens instantaneously, so fails to pick up the message.

Any idea how to convince jest to unmock setTimeout, or a Jasmine workaround?

Comment: Jest 15 appears to disable timer mocks by default http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add following code before test cases. It works for me in Jest v14.1.0 -

```
  jest.useRealTimers()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wait during your test (using `setTimeout`). Instead, use `waitFor` which is designed for exactly this use case. It will keep running the test until it passes or a timeout is reached (default of 1 second). Write your test like this:

```js
import {waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';

it('sends a message and gets a response', () => {
  processor(ws).sendMessage()`  // do a bunch of async stuff, call websocket.sendMessage()
  waitFor(() => {
    expect(ws.getResponse()).toEqual('all done');
  });
});
```

If by the end of the timeout the `expect` still doesn't pass, the test will fail. If the expect succeeds in just 0.01 seconds, the test won't take any longer to proceed.