# Jest setTimeout not pausing test

Tags: javascript, testing, timer, jestjs

```
it('has working hooks', async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Why don't I run?")
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  }, 15000)
```

I've already reviewed this answer, Jest documentation, and several GitHub threads:

[Disable Jest setTimeout mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906246/disable-jest-settimeout-mock)

Right now, the function inside the timeout doesn't run.
How can I get Jest to pause its execution of the test for 15 seconds and then run the inner function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
it('has working hooks', async () => {
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Why don't I run?")
    expect(true).toBe(true)
    res()
  }, 15000))
})
```

or

```
it('has working hooks', done => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Why don't I run?")
    expect(true).toBe(true)
    done()
  }, 15000)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late approval. College happened. Can you offer more explanation about why this works, and the error with my code? Also, if anyone has a problem with the above, try lowering the timeout time from 15000 because there's a built in max in the testing framework it exceeds.

Comment: In your code, you didn't pass `done` parameter, so `jest` will just run till end , though you have `async`, but you didn't have any `await`  to hold the code. I may answer, the 1st one use `async` with `await`, and the 2nd one use `done`, both will hold the code. I hope I explained a little bit.

Comment: using expect before done just makes it run undefinetly for me. any idea?

Comment: I guess you are using jest in node. In this case, you need to set testEnvironment to node, check https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string.

Comment: Using `done()` leads to an eslint error in my case so I went with the first method. Thanks for both methods.

Comment: Can you explain where `done()` comes from? I tried it, but VS Code isn't helping me find it from wherever it's exported. I'm just getting a `Cannot find name 'done'` TypeScript error.

Answer (score 18):

A nice and clean way to do it (without callbacks) we can simply run an `await` and pass the `res` to `setTimeout(res, XXX)` like so:

```js
it('works with await Promise and setTimeout', async () => {
  // await 15000ms before continuing further
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 15000));

  // run your test
  expect(true).toBe(true)
});
```

Answer (score -5):

setTimeout is now available through the jest object, and it will function as you expect: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#misc.

```
it('works with jest.setTimeout', async () => {
  // pause test example for 15 seconds
  jest.setTimeout(15000)

  // run your test
  expect(true).toBe(true)
});
```

Note: If you attempt to set a timeout for 5000ms or more without the jest object, jest will error and let you know to use jest.setTimeout instead.

Comment: This does not pause the current test function. jest.setTimeout defines maximum amount of time a test function can take for completion. With a default of 5 seconds a jest test function will fail if it took longer. You can easily proof that if you "add  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 15000));" to your test function.